# How to highlight text with an arbitrary color

Tags: color, highlighting, soul

Okay so I have the command

```
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}}
```

in my preamble (after the inclusion of soul and xcolor packages), and colors that are already defined work perfectly well.

```
\hlc[pink]{hello}
```

gives me hello highlighted in pink. However, colour combinations don't output anything for me.

```
\hlc[cyan!50]{hello}
```

would output just

> hello

without any colour.

I want a command that's completely generic (ie. let's me highlight with any colour combination I want). Is there any nice way to do that? I don't want to repeatedly use the command `\setcolor` either. I want to be able to input the colors right in the command.

Comment: Apparently `sethlcolor` does not understand this colour specification and uses named colours only

Comment: Probably you should define the color with a name first and then use it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `\sethlcolor` macro does not understand the colour specifiction of `x!y!z` etc, it can work with named colors being defined with `\definecolor` only.

However, using `xcolor` there is a trick to support the colour definition:

`\colorlet{foo}{x!y!z!}` defines and transforms the specification into a colour named `foo` (this will overwrite an existing definition of the colour named `foo`, however.

Basically, it is similar to the macro `\let\foo\foobar` statement.
Since all happens in a group (by definition of `\hlc`), the new colour `foo` is not known outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{%
    \colorlet{foo}{#1}%
    \sethlcolor{foo}\hl{#2}}%
}



\begin{document}

\hlc[pink]{hello}

\hlc[cyan!50]{hello}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the error:
! Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.8 \hlc[pink]{hi}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: Sorry. Not getting it after copying and pasting your code. Must be typo somewhere...

Comment: @OsamaKawish: Works for me, even after copying again from here...

Comment: Yes same here. I meant there must be a bracket mistake or something in mine after I tried changing by hand on my old code.

Comment: @OsamaKawish: Which is hard to detect for me since I don't see your code...

Comment: It's fine. I can figure these out on my own. :)

Comment: This is brilliant. Works great for me using custom colors predefined such as `\definecolor{coral}{HTML}{F45B69}`