# Emphasizing Arabic text characters

Tags: arabic

Regarding the "Arabic Language", words in such language are written such that the letters are connected, unlike English where words are written such that each letter is written separately. However, upon trying to emphasize any letter in Arabic text through the use of any of the options below:

- Underline: The letter disappear and the word letters are separated
- Bold:  The word letters are separated
- Italic:  The word letters are separated
- Highlight:  The letter disappear and the word letters are separated
- Frame/Border: Don't know how to do it (Put a single letter in a word in a frame/Border, while maintaining word structure), but I am sure the same problem will arise if I tried placing a single letter in a word into a frame/border[image]

In such cases, the text letters become separated and are no longer connected. Is there a way to emphasize letters through the use of various options while maintaining the word structure where the letters remain attached and are not disconnected??
Here is a MWE where I use Lualatex, notice I used the command described in [How to highlight text with an arbitrary color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352956/how-to-highlight-text-with-an-arbitrary-color) so as to allow custom color regarding highlight command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.9}
\sethlcolor{mygrey}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{%
            \colorlet{foo}{#1}%
            \sethlcolor{foo}\hl{#2}}%
            }

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{english}{This is the word under study}\\
جنوب
\\
\\
\foreignlanguage{english}{Bold}\\
جن
\textbf{و}
ب
\\
\\
\foreignlanguage{english}{underline}\\
جن
\ul{و}
ب
\\
\\
\foreignlanguage{english}{italic}\\
جن
\textit{و}
ب
\\
\\
\foreignlanguage{english}{highlight}\\
جن
\hlc[gray!25]{و}
ب
\\
\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: `soul` package use a font which does not contain Arabic script.

Comment: @Salim, is there an alternative package??

Comment: For entire word a colorbox is enough, but for a single letter we lose connection between letters may be this can be done with `lua`.

Comment: coloring the glyphs should be possible with luacolor or the new color scheme in luaotfload.  But everything else interrupts the font shaping. soul is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I can somehow manage to avoid using bold and underlined options but is there a workaround for using frames & borders around letters while maintaining connected letters?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, upon loading the packages (luacolor) & (luaotfload), I get the same results, nothing happens. Can you provide any hints regarding their use for this specific situation since the documentation for such packages is a bit vivid.

Comment: @SalimBou, how can I use the above approach to highlight, or even underline the accents in arabic letters as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355666/textarabic-highlight-specifc-letters-or-elements-of-text

Comment: @SalimBou, If you may please consider this question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621446/highlighting-diacritical-marks-and-making-optional-bounding-boxes

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, do you have any suggestions with regard to this question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/621446/102379

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robert's answer with babel, added `\arbboxi`, `\arbboxr`, `\arbboxl` and `\arbboxb` for isolated, beginning, end, middle form of  letters. boxes are drawn with TikZ you can customize them with `boxstyle` as you like using `\tikzset{boxstyle/.append style={...}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage [bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ulem}
    
\newcommand{\ulinei}[1]{\uline{#1}}
\newcommand{\ulinel}[1]{^^^^200d\uline{^^^^200d#1}}
\newcommand{\uliner}[1]{\uline{#1^^^^200d}^^^^200d}
\newcommand{\ulineb}[1]{^^^^200d\uline{^^^^200d#1^^^^200d}^^^^200d}

\tikzset{boxstyle/.style={draw=red,inner sep=0pt,fill=yellow}}

\newcommand{\arbboxi}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{#1};%
}
\newcommand{\arbboxl}[1]{%
  ^^^^200d\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{^^^^200d#1};%
}
\newcommand{\arbboxr}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{#1^^^^200d};^^^^200d%
}
\newcommand{\arbboxb}[1]{%
  ^^^^200d\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{^^^^200d#1^^^^200d};^^^^200d%
}
    
\begin{document}

\Large

جنوب 

\hrulefill

\uliner{ج}نوب
ج\ulineb{ن}وب
جن\ulinel{و}ب
جنو\ulinei{ب}

\hrulefill

\arbboxr{ج}نوب
ج\arbboxb{ن}وب
جن\arbboxl{و}ب
جنو\arbboxi{ب}

\tikzset{boxstyle/.append style={dashed,draw=blue,font=\bfseries,fill=green}}

\hrulefill

\arbboxr{ج}نوب
ج\arbboxb{ن}وب
جن\arbboxl{و}ب
جنو\arbboxi{ب}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

## **Update 24/02/2020**

I have created a command `\FormatChar` (thanks to @David Carlisle https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529439/54817)
you can apply any commands for a character in Arabic word, the command can also be used with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage [bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ulem}

\def\connecti{i}
\def\connectr{r}
\def\connectl{l}
\def\connectb{b}

\makeatletter
\def\FormatChar#1#2#3#4{%
\let\joineri\@firstofone%
\let\joinerii\@firstofone%
\def\formatcs{#1}%
\def\temp{#3}%
\if\temp\connectb%
\else
 \if\temp\connectr%
 \let\joinerii\@gobble%
 \else
   \if\temp\connectl%
   \let\joineri\@gobble%
   \else    
      \if\temp\connecti%
      \let\joineri\@gobble\let\joinerii\@gobble%
      \else
      \@latex@error
      {\temp is not available for contextual forms}
      \fi%
   \fi%
 \fi%   
\fi%
\xFormatChar{#2}#4}%
\def\xFormatChar#1#2{\ifnum#1=1\joineri{^^^^200d}%
\formatcs{\joineri{^^^^200d}#2\joinerii{^^^^200d}}%
\joinerii{^^^^200d}\expandafter\@gobbletwo%
    \else#2\fi\xFormatChar{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
\makeatother
    
\tikzset{charboxstyle/.style={draw=red,inner sep=0pt,fill=yellow}}
    
\newcommand{\charbox}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[charboxstyle]{#1};%
}

\begin{document}

%\FormatChar{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} 
% #1: Command
% #2: Position of char (number)
% #3: Contextual forms r , l , b , i
% #4: Word
    
\Huge

\FormatChar{\uline}{1}{l}
{جنوب}
%
\FormatChar{\textcolor{blue}}{2}{b}
{جنوب}
%
\FormatChar{\textcolor{red}}{3}{r}
{جنوب}
%
\FormatChar{\charbox}{4}{i}
{جنوب}
%
\tikzset{charboxstyle/.append style={dashed,draw=blue,fill=green,text=orange}}
%
\FormatChar{\charbox}{1}{l}
{جنوب}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## **Update 28/02/2020**

For multiple letters macro `\FormatChars` can be used (thanks to @egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529602/54817 )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage [bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,main]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
    
\tikzset{charboxstyle/.style={draw=red,inner sep=0pt,fill=yellow}}

\newcommand{\charbox}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[charboxstyle]{#1};%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatChars}{m >{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m O{i} m}
 {
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \inputcs { #1 }
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \joinb {^^^^200d}
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \joine {^^^^200d}
  \str_case:nnF { #3 }
   {
    { i } { \let\joinb\relax\let\joine\relax }
    { r } { \let\joine\relax }
    { l } { \let\joinb\relax }
    { b } { }
   }
   {
  \msg_error:nn {}{#2~is~not~available~for~contextual~forms,~try~with~r,~l,~or~b} 
   } 
      % #2 is passed as two braced arguments
  \_FormatChars:nnn #2 { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \_FormatChars:nnn
 {
  % let's analyze the first two args
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
   {% no hyphen in the argument
    \___FormatChars:nnn { #1 } { #1 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF { \tl_if_blank_p:n { #1 } } { \tl_if_blank_p:n { #2 } }
     {% argument is -n or m- or -
      \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
       {
        \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
         {% argument is -
          \joinb\inputcs{\joinb #3\joine}\joine
         }
         {% argument is -n
          \___FormatChars:nnn { 1 } { #2 } { #3 }
         }
       }
       {% argument is m-
        \___FormatChars:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { #3 }
       }
     }
     {% argument is m-n
      \___FormatChars:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \___FormatChars:nnn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 > #2 > 0 }
   {
    #3
   }
   {
    \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { 1 } { #1 - 1 }
    \joinb\inputcs{\joinb \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { #1 } { #2 }\joine }\joine
    \tl_range:nnn { #3 } { #2 + 1 } { -1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

%\FormatChars{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4} 

% #1  : command to apply on range ex : \uline 
% #2  : range of letters ex : 2-6
% #3  : type of connection : i , r , l , b (default i)
% #4  : word    

\Huge

\FormatChars{\uline}{1-3}
{جنوب}
%
\FormatChars{\textcolor{blue}}{2-3}[r]
{جنوب}
%
\FormatChars{\textcolor{red}}{2-}[r]
{جنوب}
%
\FormatChars{\charbox}{4}
{جنوب}
%
\tikzset{charboxstyle/.append style={draw=blue,fill=black,text=white}}
%
\FormatChars{\charbox}{-2}[l]
{جنوب}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, is there a way to also add the bold option, make bold letters while maintaining connection between letters??? In addition, regarding the frames, can we add an option to the command to control whether the frame is dashed, continued... in addition to the line thickness?

Comment: Answer updated you can change or add more options for `\arbbox` style with
`\tikzset{boxstyle/.append style={...}}`

Comment: OK, regarding the bold option, can it be used while maintaining connection between letters???

Comment: Yes with `\tikzset{boxstyle/.append style={draw=none,fill=none,font=\bfseries}}` 
but difference between  letters appears at connections in one side a thick letter  and  in the other a thin.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529341/multiple-cases-for-xstring-package

Comment: Any suggestions why the redefined command below does not work. the compilation runs with no errors, but, output is unconnected

Comment: \newcommand{\arbbox}[6]{%
\tikzset{boxstyle/.style={#1,draw=#2,font=#3,fill=#4}}
\IfEqCase{#5}{%
        {l}{^^^^200d\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{^^^^200d#6};%
        }%
        {b}{^^^^200d\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{^^^^200d#6^^^^200d};^^^^200d%
   }%
        {r}{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{#6^^^^200d};^^^^200d%
        }%
        {i}{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]\node(x)[boxstyle]{#6};%
        }%
        % you can add more cases here as desired
    }[\PackageError{arbbox}{Undefined option to arbbox: #1}{}]%          
}%

Comment: Is there a way to make such macro (Format char and format chars) work with glyphs? as sown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355666/textarabic-highlight-specifc-letters-or-elements-of-text

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558813/formatting-multiple-characters-and-glyhs-accents-within-the-same-word

Comment: \FormatChar command, the formatted letter is seperated from the word, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you consider the Question in the link below:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621446/highlighting-diacritical-marks-and-making-optional-bounding-boxes

Answer (score 8):

The following can be improved in various ways (e.g. using tikz is probably a bit overkill and also doesn't work well in RTL mode; there should be a way to select the glyphs which gets a frame and to change the colors; glue and other nodes are currently ignored, so it works only for single words) but it shows that it is basically possible to inspect the words, get the dimensions and draw something which doesn't interfere with the font shaping:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage [bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}


\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\myword

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function frameword (boxnum)
   local head = tex.box[boxnum].head
   local colortable={"yellow","red","blue","green"}
   local GLYPH           = node.id("glyph")
   local widthtable={}
   local heighttable={}
   local depthtable={}
   for n in node.traverse(head) do
    local id = n.id
    if id == GLYPH then
      table.insert(widthtable,n.width);
      table.insert(heighttable,n.height);
      table.insert(depthtable,n.depth);
      texio.write_nl (" WIDTH ".. n.width .. " CHAR " .. n.char)
    else
      texio.write_nl ("????")
    end
   end
    for i = table.getn(widthtable), 1, -1 do
     color = colortable[math.fmod(i,4)+1]
     tex.sprint("\\printrectangle{"..color.."}{".. widthtable[i] .."}{" .. heighttable[i].."}{" .. depthtable[i] .."}")
    end
end
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
جنوب 



\newcommand\printrectangle[4]{\tikz[overlay]\draw[#1,opacity=0.5](0,-#4sp)rectangle(#2sp,#3sp);\hspace{#2sp}}
\savebox\myword{\textdir TRT جنوب} 



\leavevmode\foreignlanguage{english}{\directlua{frameword(\the\myword)}\llap{\usebox\myword}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you must notice that the option [Renderer=HarfBuzz] in the amiri font caused the letters to become seperated so I had to remove it

Comment: @Silva My screenshots show what I get. But you need to use lualatex-dev (and a current texlive which has luahbtex as engine) to make use of the Harfbuzz library.

Comment: lualatex-dev is still beta right, is it safe to use? Anyway, if it is not of any annoyance to you (I know you're a bit busy and also mentioned that "The following can be improved in various ways", so you expect other users to further enhance such solution), the code is a bit too much for me, can you provide any hints regarding setting a command with optional arguments to set which letter in the word to be framed, set frame color, line thickness, line type (dashed, continous), as well as backgrond color (Highlight), since the command it not defined in the preamble and is defined mid-document.

Comment: no lualatex-dev is not beta. Currently lualatex and lualatex-dev use the same latex, only that lualatex-dev uses the luahbtex engine. It is fine and it is much better with scripts like arabic than the luatex engine. And no, I don't have the time to expand the code. I already spent too much time on it.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I added below a rather primitive approach for drawing frames.  Then, in the document itself, I added the invisible ^^^^200d mark at the appropriate places.

Not an answer, but only a suggestion.  In my opinion, coloring the glyphs is the way to go in Arabic typographically speaking.  Underlining may also be considered.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}

\newcommand{\ulinel}[1]{^^^^200d\uline{^^^^200d#1}}
\newcommand{\uliner}[1]{\uline{#1^^^^200d}^^^^200d}
\newcommand{\ulineb}[1]{^^^^200d\uline{^^^^200d#1^^^^200d}^^^^200d}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arbbox}{O{white} O{white} m}{%
  \fboxsep=0pt%
  \fcolorbox{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{arab}
  ^ganUb
  ^gan\arbcolor[blue]{U}b
  ^gan\ulinel{U}b
  ^ga\ulineb{n}Ub
  ^gan‍\arbbox[red][yellow]{‍U}b
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this while using Unicode fonts instead of arabic transliterations? I do not have the opportunity to use arabic transliterations.

Comment: @Silva For the record, `arabluatex` also provides `\txarb{}` and `\begin{txarab}...\end{txarab}` for inserting Unicode Arabic.  That said, the `babel` way is excellent.

Comment: So I can use the exact above code with babel?

Comment: Also, regarding the bold option, can it be used while maintaining connection between letters???

Comment: @Silva Yes, with `babel`, just remove `arabluatex` and its Arabic environments, and type away in Arabic. `xparse` is required for building commands with `\NewDocumentCommand` and `luacolor` for coloring Arabic glyphs as said by Ulrike.  You may pattern your commands after the above `\ulineX` and relplace `uline` with `textbf` and it will work.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that Ulrike updated her answer above (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528416/72582).  In my opinion, this is the best approach for drawing frames around glyphs.

Comment: Yes she did, in fact it is a wonderful approach, but,it just needs a little bit of tweaking

Answer (score 4):

With luacolor you can color the glyphs too

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{english}{This is the word under study}\\
جنوب\\
\color{yellow}ج\color{red}ن\color{blue}و\color{green}ب 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ,Ok, what about highlighting them, can this be done? Also how is the package (Luaotfload) used?

Comment: see my other answer. The printrectangle could have a background instead of only a frame.