# How to color an Arabic letter in a word without adding extra length or Tatweel?

Tags: xetex, color, arabic

I'd like to color in xelatex a letter in a word.

```
\documentclass[14pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex}
\linespread{1.6}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{KFGQPC HAFS Uthmanic Script}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
الْ\char"200D\textcolor{red}{\char"200Dقَ\char"200D}\char"200Dلَمُ
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

It's coloring the Qaf letter but it's also adding some length to both sides of the letter. I assume that is a Tatweel or Kashidah:

[image]

But my desired result is like this:

[image]

So, how can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Make a small but *complete* example. That makes testing much easier.

Comment: sorry, it's my first question. Do you mean, I should've added smaller images?

Comment: You should have added a complete (small) document code, starting with \documentclass.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - does it look good now?

Comment: This can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529195/54817

Comment: @SalimBou - thanks! My text is huge and I think a solution without `tikz` would be better.

Comment: The macro do not involve tikz, you can use it in your case like this \FormatChars{\textcolor{red}}{3}[b]{القلم}

Comment: @SalimBou - cool, I will try that solution, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this with xelatex. So, I decided to go with lualatex as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529184/209245

```
\documentclass[14pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{KFGQPC HAFS Uthmanic Script}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\begin{document}
ٱﻝْ\textcolor{red}{ﻕَ}ﻞَﻣُ
\end{document}
```

which produced this result:

[image]