# Modifying the multiple letters macro \FormatChars

Tags: macros, formatting, characters, letters

Regarding the multiple letters macro "\FormatChars" posted in [Emphasizing Arabic text characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528341/emphasizing-arabic-text-characters).
Is there a way to modify this macro such that:

- You can select any set of characters you want to modify despite of their arrangement within the word, I have noticed that you can only select a consecutive set of letters (so you select letters from 1 till 3, 2 till 4...) yet there is a need to select non-consecutive characters within the same word (the first and third letters for example, or second and fifth letter...etc)
- Set the formatting to be applied for each of the selected characters seperately so that a different type of formatting can be applied to each of the selected characters instead of applying the same formatting to all of the specified characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can  use [`lua-ul`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul) package which highlight or underline  letters of word without breaking ligatures, kerning, font shaping.

You can also create your own format of underlining with `\newunderlinetype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul}
\begin{document}

\Huge

\highLight[red]{ج}\underLine{نو}\highLight[yellow]{ب} \quad
\textcolor{red}{ج}\underLine{نو}\textcolor{blue}{ب} \quad
\underLine{\textcolor{red}{ج}نو}\highLight[green]{\textcolor{red}{ب}} \quad
% Coloring diacritical marks
ج%
\textcolor{blue}{َ}% fatha
نوب%
\textcolor{red}{ٌ}% tanween

 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the definitions of the diacritical marks in lualatex for each language , and how does the command % fatha... work? IS there a reference to emphaszie such type of syntax?

Comment: @Silva I have just inserted fatha `َ` and tanween `ٌ`  inside `\textcolor{blue}{}` and `\textcolor{red}{}`  commands.

Comment: @Silva you need to add `luacolor` package without it you lose font shaping in case of using `\textcolor` (lualatex engine).