# Highlight text with \fcolorbox without space

Tags: color

I wanted to highlight part of my sequence. The problem is that `\fcolorbox` shifts the text so that the sequences are no longer aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{red!80}{yellow}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
    %   \caption{}
        %\label{tab:my-table}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Seq1 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggc\cbox{tgc}cccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
            Seq2 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
            Seq3 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
            & *****************************************       
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I remove the space inserted by the `\fcolorbox` ?

PS: `\makebox()` did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the impact of the space and rule inserted around the box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,array}

\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% Remove impact of space and rule inserted by box
  \fcolorbox{red!80}{yellow}{\strut#1}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l >{\ttfamily} l }
  Seq1 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggc\cbox{tgc}cccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
  Seq2 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
  Seq3 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
       & *********************************************
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also set the `\fcolorbox` in the background by capturing the position of the text (using [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module) and placing a `\phantom` element via [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,array,zref-savepos,eso-pic}

\newcounter{cboxcntr}
\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{{%
  \stepcounter{cboxcntr}% Allow for unique \cbox
  \zsavepos{cbox-\thecboxcntr}% Capture (x,y) coordinate of cbox
  #1%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \noexpand\AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \noexpand\setlength{\noexpand\fboxsep}{.5\noexpand\fboxsep}% Reduce the fbox padding
      \noexpand\hspace*{\dimexpr\zposx{cbox-\thecboxcntr}sp-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}%
      \noexpand\raisebox{\zposy{cbox-\thecboxcntr}sp}{%
        \noexpand\fcolorbox{red!80}{yellow}{\noexpand\phantom{\noexpand\ttfamily\noexpand\strut#1}}%
      }%
    }%
  }}\x%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l >{\ttfamily} l }
  Seq1 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggc\cbox{tgc}cccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
  Seq2 & gactttgtgg\cbox{aca}tcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
  Seq3 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgac\cbox{ctcg}tgtac \\
       & *********************************************
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer is inspired to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352956/how-to-highlight-text-with-an-arbitrary-color?rq=1).

With this code (where I changed the color for more readability):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{%
        \colorlet{foo}{#1}%
        \sethlcolor{foo}\hl{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\hlc[red!40!yellow]{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        %   \caption{}
        %\label{tab:my-table}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Seq1 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggc\mybox{tgc}cccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
            Seq2 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
            Seq3 & gactttgtggacatcaacgtcggctgccccatcgacctcgtgtac \\
            & *****************************************       
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

You have the desired result:
[image]