# change highlight color in easyReview package or other way

Tags: color, packages

In easyReview package there is a command for highlighting a text. But I so much have tried to change the color of highlight. The default color is yellow but I wanted to have for example darkorange color defined [here](https://latexcolor.com/).

In this package there are ways to change the color of other commands for example:

```
\renewcommand{\alertColor}{\textcolor{%new alert color%}}
\renewcommand{\removeColor}{\textcolor{%new remove color%}}
\renewcommand{\addColor}{\textcolor{%new add color%}}
```

but there is no any way to change the highlight color.

I tried other methods to highlight. For instance, using instrucions on this [page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352956/how-to-highlight-text-with-an-arbitrary-color) but there is a proble. When there exist a command of `\ref{}` or `\cite{}` in the text, the `\hcl` defined on that page doesnot work!!!

Comment: the easyReview package uses the soul package for highlighting `\hl` command.  If you only want highlighting you can use soul directly. Please use full working MWE it is easier to get help if you do.

Comment: `easyReview` package use the command `\hl` from `soul` package, which highlight color can be set using `\sethlcolor{...}`.

Comment: Use  `\RequirePackage{soul}`
`\sethlcolor{mycolor}`